# How do I set different default permissions for files vs folders using setfacl?

Tags: debian, permissions, ext4, setfacl

I have a folder `/stuff` that is owned by `root:stuff` with `setgid` set so all new folders' have group set to `stuff`.

I want it so:

- New files have `rw-rw----`:

  - **User**: read and write
  - **Group**: read and write
  - **Other**: none
- New folders have `rwxrwx---`:

  - **User**: read, write, and execute
  - **Group**: read, write, and execute
  - **Other**: none

If I set default ACLs with `setfacl` then it seems to apply to both files and folders. For me, this is fine for **Other** since both files and folders get no permissions:

```
setfacl -d -m o::---- /stuff
```

But what do I do for **User** and **Group**? If I do something like above then it will be set on all files and folders.

And I can't use `umask`.

I have a shared drive. I am trying to make it so folks in `stuff` can read/write/execute but nobody else (Other) can. And I wan to make sure that by default files do not get the execute bit set, regardless of what the account's `umask` is.

Comment: If the only difference is the execute bit, then look into `X` instead of `x` as the mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to differentiate between files and directories using **setfacl** only.
Instead you can workaround the issue with using **inotify-tools** to detect new created files/dirs, then apply the correct ACLs for each one recursively:

1- You have to install inotify-tools package first.

2- Recover the default /stuff directory acls

```
sudo setfacl -bn /stuff
```

3- SetGID

```
sudo chmod g+s /stuff
```

4- Execute the following script in the background for testing purpose, for a permanent solution wrap it within a service.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo inotifywait -m -r -e create --format '%w%f' /stuff | while read NEW
do
    # when a new dir created
    if [ -d "$NEW" ]; then
        sudo setfacl -m u::rwx "$NEW"
        sudo setfacl -m g::rwx "$NEW"
   # when a new file created
    elif [ -f "$NEW" ]; then
        sudo setfacl -m u::rw "$NEW"
        sudo setfacl -m g::rw "$NEW"
fi
    # setting no permissions for others
    sudo setfacl -m o:--- "$NEW"
done
```

Comment: How well will this work when a lot of files/folders are added in bulk?

Comment: Yes for sure you can try it yourself, this will be handled sequentially.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark it as resolved if the above helped you.